# Does Swing come with Calendar and time field components?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, datepicker

I would like to have Date and Time fields in my jPanel application so that the user can pick a date and time from a drop down lists.  Is there any Swing component out there which I can use rather than having to re-invent the wheel??!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try swingx [JXDatePicker](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXDatePicker.html) component.

Comment: the above is to version 0.8 from 2007 - not even SwingX has such long release cycles :-) (didn't even know they are still available, after the migration of java.net) Latest release is http://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/1.6.2/

Comment: I'd like to insert the value derived from this JXDatePicker into a Date field in Java DB.  How should I get ONLY date off this controller in a way that time is represented as dd/mm/yyyy and nothing else??!

Comment: Please ask a new question so as not to clutter up the comment area

Answer (score 2):

Also consider the recently updated, bean-based [`JCalendar`](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/). More here [jcalendar](/questions/tagged/jcalendar).

Answer (score 1):

http://jdatechooser.sourceforge.net/