# How do I dynamically fill a combo box in Java?

Tags: java, combobox

I am doing a Event Scheduler

Now I have the months going. But if the user selects lets february month how do I dynamically fill the number of days based on that selection into a combo box?

Now I know :

```
int days = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

gives me the number of days, so how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Hi, did your course also cover `for` and `while` loops?

Comment: Looks like homework. In future, please tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Swing come with Calendar and time field components?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870949/does-swing-come-with-calendar-and-time-field-components)

Comment: That's not an exact duplicate.  This question is about event scheduling and the other question is about pre-built components.

Answer (score 0):

You want to attach an action listener to your first combo box which will be called each time you select an option. You can then put the code in the action performed method to change the combo box model depending on what was selected in the first combo box. You can find everything you need to do it in the Java tutorials http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Comment: downvoted as you link to the tutorial index where there are hundreds of topics, i found you answer of no help at all.